# compilation of VLC for Android fail

Tags: android, compilation, vlc

I'm trying to compile vlc using the following instructions http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile. 
i get the vlc source using git but when i'm doing the next command:

```
cd extras/contrib
```

`./bootstrap -t arm-eabi -d android`

i'm getting this error:

```
[contrib] No install dir specified, using '/android-sdk-mac_x86/vlc-android/extras/contrib/hosts/arm-eabi'
[contrib] *****************************************************************
[contrib] * If you need contribs with all debug information, run this     *
[contrib] * line and compile the libraries on your own.                   *
[contrib] * CONTRIBS_RELEASE=no ./bootstrap                               *
[contrib] *****************************************************************
[contrib] Using 1 processor(s)
```

when i make the next step that is 'make' i got the following failure;

```
make -C build-src tools
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `tools'.
make -C build-src
(cd zlib; CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-9/arch-arm" CXX="arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-9/arch-arm" LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld" RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib" AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar" STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip" ./configure --prefix=/android-sdk-mac_x86/vlc-android/extras/contrib/hosts/arm-eabi --static && make install)
Building static library libz.a version 1.2.5 with arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-9/arch-arm.
Checking for off64_t... No.
Checking for fseeko... No.
Checking for unistd.h... No.
Checking whether to use vs[n]printf() or s[n]printf()... using s[n]printf().
Checking for snprintf() in stdio.h... No.
  WARNING: snprintf() not found, falling back to sprintf(). zlib
  can build but will be open to possible buffer-overflow security
  vulnerabilities.
Checking for return value of sprintf()... No.
  WARNING: apparently sprintf() does not return a value. zlib
  can build but will be open to possible string-format security
  vulnerabilities.
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-9/arch-arm -I/android-sdk-mac_x86/vlc-android/extras/contrib/hosts/arm-eabi/include  -DNDEBUG -D__STDC_VERSION__=199901L -I/android-ndk-r5b//sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include -I/android-ndk-r5b//sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include -isystem /android-sdk-mac_x86/vlc-android/extras/contrib/hosts/arm-eabi/include -I/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -DNO_FSEEKO -DNO_snprintf -DHAS_sprintf_void -I/android-sdk-mac_x86/vlc-android/extras/contrib/hosts/arm-eabi/include  -DNDEBUG -D__STDC_VERSION__=199901L -I/android-ndk-r5b//sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include -I/android-ndk-r5b//sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include -isystem /android-sdk-mac_x86/vlc-android/extras/contrib/hosts/arm-eabi/include -I/android-ndk-r5b//platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include  -c -o adler32.o adler32.c
make[2]: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [adler32.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.zlib] Error 2
make: *** [using-src] Error 2
```

anyone can help? i'm using mac OS X 10.6.6

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given prior Linux CLI experience, the best I can tell you is that it doesn't look like your tool-chain is fully initialized and needs some setup. Below is a link that documents initialization for a MAC build environment:

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have set your NDK installation properly.

1. Download the latest Android NDK.
2. Unzip and move the extracted “android-ndk-r6″ directory to “/Applications”, so you end up with “/Applications/android-ndk-r6″.
3. Edit “~/.profile” to add the following:
   export ANDROID_NDK=/Applications/android-ndk-r5b
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK:$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin

The PATH was the key to solve this kind of problem to me. Because it makes possible to find and use "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc".

Refer to this web site.
http://www.doitscared.com/632/eclipse-indigo-for-android-development-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Comment: Please add a summary of what the link is pointing to, in case the link ever fails.